# subscribe users automatically to the asset publisher liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, subscription

Is there any option to subscribe users automatically to the asset publisher? 
I saw this:

message.boards.subscribe.by.default=true

but, I need it for the asset publisher

Thank you!!

Comment: I try with this: asset.publisher.subscribe.by.default=true, but itsn't work

Comment: Are the other mail subscriptions firing correctly for you or is it just this particular property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message.boards.subscribe.by.default` subscribes a user to the message board thread *they're answering* to - e.g. *after they interacted* with the message board.

What would be the interaction with AssetPublisher that you're intending to trigger this automatic subscription? There's typically only the author(s) of an asset publisher adding articles, and they don't need to interact with AssetPublisher in order to make other articles appear because AssetPublisher only filters and shows whatever matches the current criteria.

This is a long way to say "no, there's no such property". However, there's Liferay's API, which you can use to codify the criteria for subscription. This will naturally be more effort than setting a property, but it's your only option.